# Functor in STL/Boost which extracts value from pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, stl, functor

I need a functor which does a very simple thing, basically this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Extract
{
    T & operator()(T *t)
    {
        return *t;
    }
};
```

I don't want to replicate code, and I believe that such a simple and handy piece of code should already exist somewhere. I've tried looking for it, but with no success.

Comment: why not simply use '*', instead of `Extract`?

Comment: Can you show some use cases for this ?

Comment: I think the use case is same as for `std::plus` and similar functors.

Comment: @Juraj: could you enlighten us with one or two sentences?

Comment: @Zane: `transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), Extract());`

Comment: Yep, I confirm what @Juraj wrote. Such `Extract` functor would be handy when dealing with STL/Boost algorithms which operate on iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to iterate over some container and do smth with pointers in it? Or even build a higher order function based on existed (like std::plus & etc)...

for that purpose boost library have few solutions:

- indirect_iterator from [boost::iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html)
- indirected adaptor from [boost::range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indirected.html)

both are capable to work not only w/ raw pointers but include support for some smart one...

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a syntax error in your example, I think you are trying to overload the function call operator as such:

```
template<typename T>
struct Extract
{
    T& operator()(T *t)
    {
        return *t;
    }
};
```

Next, it seems that this is converting a pointer to a reference. You can do this using [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) and [`std::cref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) in the standard library. They create a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) from a value so you would deference the pointer argument before sending it to `std::ref`.

How yours is used:

```
Extract<int> ex;
int n = 1;
int* n_ptr = &n;
int& n2 = ex(n_ptr);
```

How `std::ref` would be used:

```
int n = 1;
int* n_ptr = &n;
int& n2 = std::ref(*n_ptr);
```

Comment: `std::ref` is not what OP wants. He wants a functor which returns a referece given a pointer.

Comment: @aleguna Isn't a function a kind of functor?

Comment: @BretKuhns, it is, but `std::ref` doesn't do what OP wants